# certbot-auto can't extend license to new domain (403 Forbidden)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have an Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean from which I'm running mainly a single domain, with multiple subdomains: `domain.com`, `sub1.domain.com`, `sub2.domain.com`, etc. Each has it's own Virtual Host.

The Virtual Hosts are all configured via their own config files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
domain.conf // port 80
domain-le-ssl.conf // port 443
sub1.domain.conf
sub1.domain-le-ssl.conf
etc...
```

I have an SSL certificate setup for all of them via Let'sEncrypt / Certbot, forcing a redirect to HTTPS on all of them. Until now this has been working just fine. However, I now want to add another subdomain, `sub3.domain.com`.

I copied the conf files for `sub2.domain.com` and changed the relevant paths, servername, etc.:

**sub3.domain.conf:**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub3.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub3_domain/html
    <Directory "/var/www/sub3_domain/html">
        # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
        RewriteEngine on
        # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # Otherwise forward the request to index.html
        RewriteRule . index.html
    </Directory>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub3.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**sub3.domain-le-ssl.conf:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub3.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub3_domain/html
    <Directory "/var/www/sub3_domain/html">
        # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
        RewriteEngine on
        # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # Otherwise forward the request to index.html
        RewriteRule . index.html
    </Directory>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

With all this setup, I then ran `certbot-auto` to renew my certificate and add the new subdomain to the certificate. When prompted for which sites I wanted to add, I left it blank and pressed enter for 'all' (sub3.domain *was* included in that list). It then correctly picked up that I had added a new subdomain and asked if I wanted to expand the license to cover the new domain. Hit 'e' for expand, and off it went, performing challenges.

Right away, things seemed a little off, since for all my existing domains, it performed `tls-sni-01` challenges, but for my new one, it performed a `http-01` challenge:

```
tls-sni-01 for domain.com
tls-sni-01 for sub1.domain.com
tls-sni-01 for sub2.domain.com
http-01 for sub3.domain.com
```

Sure enough, within a few seconds, I had the following output:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: sub3.domain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://sub3.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/lKPYKHvStBag4YFzmfRbO7UpEINC4SYjEPMj-R_J-BY:
   "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
   <html><head>
   <title>403 Forbidden</title>
   </head><body>
   <h1>Forbidden</h1>
   <p"
```

To my knowledge, I don't have any particular or specific .htaccess or other such rules that would result in any subdirectory being forbidden - and in any case, why a different test for that one server?

I also tried this without copying the `sub3.domain-le-ssl.conf` file, since I do believe that's actually generated by `certbot-auto`. The process and outcome was identical.

Comment: It's probably using HTTP-01 because [LetsEncrypt recently disabled TLS-SNI-01 (and 02) for new names because an attack on it was found](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/tls-sni-challenges-disabled-for-most-new-issuance/50316). But why HTTP-01 is 403ing I don't know.

Comment: Hmm, well that does help with my troubleshooting nonetheless! I can cross that off as a potential cause for the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs for authentication errors?